# Why are sed commands quote-marked?

Tags: sed

If we start Sed commands by `sed` and scope them with `sed /X/Y/ FILE`, why are they generally being quote-marked as with `sed "s/X/Y/g" FILE`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To protect them from the shell. Not that a string like `s/X/Y/` needs it, but the moment you do something that that involves whitespace or shell special characters, you'll need to add the quotes anyway. In a way, it's easier to just quote from the get-go, since it does no harm anyway.

This works without the quotes:

```
$ echo abcdefg | sed s/abc/xyz/ 
xyzdefg
```

while this would blow in a few interesting ways without them:

```
$ printf 'abc\nabc\n' | sed -E '$s/(abc|def)/xyz zyx/'
abc
xyz zyx
```

Comment: To be clear, rather than thinking about this in terms of adding quotes when you need to, you should always use single quotes around all strings (including scripts) by default, change to double quotes if/when you need to (e.g. to expand variables), and remove them completely if/when you need to (e.g. for filename expansion). See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: ilkkachue, this explanation applies only to Bourne shells right?

Comment: I mean to ask, is `To protect them from the shell` applies only to Bourne shells or to all *nix shell existing today?

Comment: @htmlizer, no, a lot of shells have special characters that need to be quoted. E.g. that second command breaks without the quotes in (t)csh and fish too, for the same reasons: `$` marks variable expansion, so `$s` doesn't stay intact (or might give an error if undefined); the `()` have special meanings (they start a command substitution in fish); the `|` makes a pipeline (the same way it was used after `printf` there); and the space breaks the argument to sed into distinct words. I don't know about `rc` or `es` or such. Zsh is close enough to sh or csh, I think.